How to set data type for OWL restriction using DotNetRDF?
I want to make the TestClassB class equivalent to the A class and to OWLDataProperties "hasURI" which has several xsd:strings, wrap all of them in a single equivalentclass. I coded some parts using dotnetrdf classes but it's almost impossible to wrap all the classes in a single equivalentclass using owl:restriction, probably this library is no longer supported.
var g = new OntologyGraph();
 var baseURI = "semanticweb/hp/ontologies/2024/11/11";

 //OntoClass A
 OntologyClass testClassA = g.CreateOntologyClass(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_A"));
 testClassA.AddType(UriFactory.Create(OntologyHelper.OwlClass));

 //OntoClass B
 OntologyClass testClassB = g.CreateOntologyClass(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B"));
 testClassB.AddType(UriFactory.Create(OntologyHelper.OwlClass));

 //OntoProperty
 OntologyProperty hasURI = g.CreateOntologyProperty(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/hasURI"));
 hasURI.AddDomain(testClassA);
 hasURI.AddRange(UriFactory.Create(XmlSpecsHelper.XmlSchemaDataTypeString));

 //EquivalentClass
 testClassB.AddEquivalentClass(testClassA);
 testClassB.AddEquivalentClass(hasURI);
 testClassB.AddEquivalentClass(UriFactory.Create(XmlSpecsHelper.XmlSchemaDataTypeString));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B")), 
           g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(OntologyHelper.PropertyEquivalentClass)),
          g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_A")));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B")),
           g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#intersectionOf")),
           g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("rdf:parseType")));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B")),
          g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Restriction")),
          g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#onProperty")));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(hasURI + "/TestClass_B")),
       g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#onProperty")),
       g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/hasURI")));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B")),
         g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Restriction")),
         g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#someValuesFrom")));

 g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(baseURI + "/TestClass_B")),
      g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#someValuesFrom")),
      g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(XmlSpecsHelper.XmlSchemaDataTypeString)));

 PrettyRdfXmlWriter writer = new PrettyRdfXmlWriter();
 writer.Save(g, "Example4.rdf");

After the file is saved, this part of owlClass is written to the file, which is not included at all in the part of owlRestriction, I don't know where the error could be. Please help me, how to set data type for OWL restriction using DotNetRDF.
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/11/11/TestClass_B">
    <owl:Restriction rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#onProperty" />
    <owl:Restriction rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#someValuesFrom" />
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/11/11/TestClass_A" />
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/11/11/hasURL" />
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" />
    <owl:intersectionOf rdf:resource="rdf:parseType" />
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/11/11/hasURL" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" />
  </owl:Class>

Please can you tell me how to set data type for OWL restriction using DotNetRDF?
I want that after saving this rdf that dotnetrdf automatically set it to equivalent as in the example below. Can you tell me if this can be done automatically using dotnetrdf, I looked through all the dotnetrdf documentation but couldn't find anything about owlRestriction, probably the helper class for owlRestriction which was in earlier versions has been removed by the developers of dotnetrdf, we hope that in the future the methods of the owlRestriction class will return. I want the storage part to be similar to the code below but using dotnetrdf.
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/10/untitled-ontology-60#TestClass_B">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/10/untitled-ontology-60#TestClass_A"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/10/untitled-ontology-60#hasURL"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>


[FIXED]
A few days ago I asked for help from the dotnetrdf community and unfortunately I didn't get any answer to the question I asked.
However, I didn't give up until today and finally managed to create the method I was looking for, the functionality of this method is convert primitive class to defined class using dotnetrdf.
The base OntologyGraph class still lacks ready-made methods "CreateOntologyRestriction" or "CreateOntologyIntersectionOf" which would have enabled the creation of the restriction using ready-made methods, but I hope that in the future the dotnetrdf developers will create ready-made classes and methods for Restriction and IntersectionOf. This part remains for the developers to add to new dotnetrdf versions.
I created different methods and did various research on the official website in the dotnetrdf documentation section, and searched everywhere on the internet, and today I finally completed the solution I was looking for.
I believe that this part of mine is a small contribution to the dotnetrdf community, hoping that this method will be further advanced by the dotnetrdf developers.
For educational and scientific purposes you can use my method I have created. Let's contribute to the good of dotnetrdf.
// Create a new RDF graph
IGraph graph = new Graph();

// Define namespaces
graph.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("rdf", UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"));
graph.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("owl", UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"));
graph.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("xsd", UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"));
graph.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("rdfs", UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"));

// Define the base URI for the ontology
graph.BaseUri = new Uri("http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/");

//Create the RDF:Ontology element
IUriNode ontologyNode = graph.CreateUriNode(graph.BaseUri);
graph.Assert(new Triple(ontologyNode, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:Ontology")));

//Create the Owl:Class element
IUriNode testClassA = graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(graph.BaseUri + "TestClass_A"));
IUriNode testClassB = graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(graph.BaseUri + "TestClass_B"));

// Add TestClass_A as an RDF Class
graph.Assert(new Triple(testClassA, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:Class")));
graph.Assert(new Triple(testClassB, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:Class")));

// Add 'hasURL' as a DatatypeProperty
// Define a datatype property 'hasURL' for TestClass_A
IUriNode hasURL = graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(graph.BaseUri + "hasURL"));
graph.Assert(new Triple(hasURL, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:DatatypeProperty")));
graph.Assert(new Triple(hasURL, graph.CreateUriNode("rdfs:domain"), testClassA));
graph.Assert(new Triple(hasURL, graph.CreateUriNode("rdfs:range"), graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(XmlSpecsHelper.XmlSchemaDataTypeString))));

// Add OwlClass as an RDF Class
IBlankNode owlClass = graph.CreateBlankNode();
graph.Assert(new Triple(owlClass, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:Class")));

// Add OwlIntersectionOf as an RDF IntersectionOf
INode intersection = graph.CreateUriNode("owl:intersectionOf");

// Add OwlEquivalentClass as an RDF EquivalentClass
INode equivalentClass = graph.CreateUriNode("owl:equivalentClass");

// Add URI for onProperty and set datatype for SomeValuesFrom
IUriNode onProperty = graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(graph.BaseUri + "hasURL"));
IUriNode someValuesFrom = graph.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(XmlSpecsHelper.XmlSchemaDataTypeString));

// Create a restriction: hasURL some xsd:string
INode restriction = graph.CreateBlankNode();
graph.Assert(new Triple(restriction, graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type"), graph.CreateUriNode("owl:Restriction")));
graph.Assert(new Triple(restriction, graph.CreateUriNode("owl:onProperty"), onProperty));
graph.Assert(new Triple(restriction, graph.CreateUriNode("owl:someValuesFrom"), someValuesFrom));

// Add the restriction to the class (TestClass_A) using equivalentClass
// Define restrictions, e.g., TestClass_A must have a property 'hasURL' with string values
INode definedRestriction = graph.AssertList(new List<INode>()
{
    testClassA,
    restriction
});

graph.Assert(new Triple(testClassB, equivalentClass, owlClass));
graph.Assert(new Triple(owlClass, intersection, definedRestriction));

// Write the RDF graph to an RDF/XML file
PrettyRdfXmlWriter writer = new PrettyRdfXmlWriter();
writer.Save(graph, "output.rdf");

Console.WriteLine("RDF graph has been saved to output.rdf");

Output:
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/TestClass_A"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/TestClass_B">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Resource">
                    <rdf:first rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/TestClass_A"/>
                    <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
                        <rdf:first>
                            <owl:Restriction>
                                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/hasURL"/>
                                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
                            </owl:Restriction>
                        </rdf:first>
                        <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                    </rdf:rest>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/hasURL">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2024/12/12/untitled-ontology-60/TestClass_A"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>
</rdf:RDF>

